# Условие внутри foreach

Tags: php

Подскажите, есть двумерный массив в котором ключи являются словами. не нумерацией. Т.е

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[number] => 1
[id] => 2
[name_family] => Пашка Дуров2
[minimum] => 12000
[total] => 52000
[course] => 14
[vk_link] => vk.com/id1
)

[1] => Array
(
[number] => 2
[id] => 1
[name_family] => Пашка Дуров
[minimum] => 10000
[total] => 50000
[course] => 12
[vk_link] => vk.com/id1
)

)
```

Как в текущем цикле

```
    foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $inner_key => $inner_value) {
            
            if ($inner_key == 'number' && $inner_value == $num)
            {
                $ids = ТУТ;
                $error = 0;
                break;
            }else{
                
                $error = 1;
            }
        }

    }
```

Обратиться к следующему после условия ключу `[id]` ? Аля `$inner_key + 1` (но не в этом случае)..

См. переменную `$ids` внутри условия

Comment: З.ы я знаю, что можно сделать типа $value['id'] и все. Но все же.

Comment: А какая основная цель?